# NetSuite: transform salesorder adding credit card authCode and pnRefNum ahead of item fulfilment

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm building a front-end for NS that sits outside the Webstore. Our payment gateway has a web app which is capable of creating a ref number and auth code, these need to be appended to the salesorder so the payment provider can process the payment when the order has been dispatched. Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

I'm pretty new to NS, apologies if the answer is an obvious one!

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Code: INVALID_RCRD_TRANSFRM Details: That type of record transformation is not allowed. Please see the documentation for a list of supported transformation types.
```

and here is the code I'm trying to use in my RESTlet:

```
function authorizeCreditCard(dataIn) {
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Pre Transform', JSON.stringify(dataIn));
  var customerpayment, paymentrecord
  try {
    customerpayment = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', dataIn.id, 'customerpayment', {
      "memo": dataIn.memo,
      "authCode": dataIn.authCode,
      "pnRefNum": dataIn.pnRefNum,
      "ccApproved": dataIn.ccApproved,
      "ccAvsStreetMatch": dataIn.ccAvsStreetMatch,
      "ccAvsZipMatch": dataIn.ccAvsZipMatch,
      "ccSecurityCodeMatch": dataIn.ccSecurityCodeMatch
    });
    paymentrecord = nlapiSubmitRecord(customerpayment);
  } catch (e) {
    nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', 'Transform failed', e);
  }
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Post Transform: CP', JSON.stringify(customerpayment));
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Post Transform: PR', JSON.stringify(paymentrecord));

  if (paymentrecord) {
    return {
      status: 'success',
      data: paymentrecord
    }
  }
  return {
    status: 'error',
    message: 'something went wrong'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do authorization in an external system and settlement/capture automatically in Netsuite the first step is having the same payment processor (or apparently just the same merchant bank but YMMMV) for the external system's authorization.

The the following snippets work to create a sales order that has the authorization. Later when you fulfill the order the resulting cash sale will trigger settlement and capture. If you can't configure the same processor in NS as was used for the authorization most merchant banks use a really simple to set up API.

```
function dummyExpDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    return ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + (d.getFullYear() + 1); // some future date
}
var soRec = nlapiTransformRecord('customer', custId, 'salesorder, {recordmode: 'dynamic'});
soRec.setFieldValue('paymentmethod', 'somepaymentmethodid_Visa_works'); // some payment method id for NS happiness
soRec.setFieldValue('ccnumber', '4111111111111111'); // dummy valid visa for NS happiness
soRec.setFieldValue('ccexpiredate', dummyExpDate());
soRec.setFieldValue('pnrefnum', pnref);
soRec.setFieldValue('ccapproved', 'T');
```

Comment: We're using the same gateway for the auth and the processing so that part hopefully will just work. Are you missing authcode from your example, isn't that needed to take the payment?

Comment: No. just the p/n ref

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to transform a salerorder into customerpayment. A salerorder can only transform into cashsale, invoice, itemfulfillment, returnauthorization and revenuecommitment. I think you should first convert your salerorder into an invoice and then make the payment of the customer with customerpayment.

regards

Comment: Ah yes now I see - there are only certain transformations allowed to a salesorder. My client doesn't normally invoice until after an order is fulfilled but they take auth ahead of this, leaves me a little stuck.

I had some success adding fields to the salesorder directly but couldn't add a value to the authcode field.

Comment: Do you have any errors in indicating the authcode field in the saler order? I am not functional expert in netsuite, but it seems to me that the sales order can not indicate the authCode field, that is indicated until the payment. But if your client is necessary you can create a custom field in the sales order and place the authCode there.

Please check if the answer is correct

Comment: I believe raising an invoice would mean that payment would need to be taken ahead of fulfilment. In my clients setup they require auth first then they raise the invoice once the order is fulfilled, using the webstore this is been possible. I haven't had any errors specific to authcode. I have a few more angles to try, will let you know how I get on - thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

@bknights @pedro-bustos Thanks both for your help.

I have figured it out! Largely due to your answer bknights.

You can only add an authcode etc when you first create a salesorder. This means I have to slightly refactor things but I can now add auth codes and pn refs.

Comment: If you don't mind, what did you do? When creating a Cash Sale, I'm trying to change the pnrefNum and AuthCode to a different Pre Authorization. Everytime I do, it reverts to the last pre authorization

Comment: I haven't done any SuiteScript for a long time but from what I can remember you need to set them when you first create the salesorder, you cannot add them after it exists, this might suggest you cannot update them to new values. Apologies for not being more of a help.